# Need help understanding Python linear regression model code issue (sklearn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on my first Linear Regression code using a Tech with Tim video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45ryDIPHdGg) and have run into a snag. I'm using the UCI student data from here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance

My initial model code ran fine. Then I iterated to find an optimal accuracy model, which was fine. Where it starts to go off the rails is that I tried to then inject those optimal coefficients into a new model, then run two predictions:

1. The very first model (pre-optimization loop)
2. The optimized model

Against the same x_test1 data set. To compare the two, I simply summed the squared difference between predicted and actual y values. Then I also recorded the final accuracy of both models.

I've done something wrong because the accuracy of my new "optimized" model is the same or lower as the very first model, and the difference values is very similar as well. I expected the optimized model to have much less error and a higher accuracy.

Can someone help me to see the error? I suspect the error lies after the plot section of code. Thanks in advance, code below.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from matplotlib import style

# from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# Read in Data
data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

# Slice data to include only desired headings
data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]

# Define the attribute we are trying to predict; called "label".
# Others are "features" and used to predict label
predict = "G3"

# Create array of features and label
X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

# Split data into training and testing data.  90% used for training, 10% testing
# Test size 0.1 = 10% of array size
x_train1, x_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

# Create 1st linear model and fit
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train1, y_train1)

# Compute accuracy of model
acc = linear.score(x_test1, y_test1)

# Iterate for a given number of times (max_iter) to find an optimal accuracy value and record best coefficients
loop_num = 1
max_iter = 1000
best_acc = acc
best_coef = linear.coef_
best_int = linear.intercept_
acc_counter = [acc]

print("\nInitial Accuracy: %4.3f" % acc)

while loop_num < max_iter + 1:
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
    linear2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    linear2.fit(x_train, y_train)
    acc = linear2.score(x_test, y_test)
    acc_counter.append(acc)
    print("\nAccuracy of run " + str(loop_num) + " is: %4.3f" % acc)
    if acc > best_acc:
        print("\n\tBetter accuracy found.")
        best_acc = acc
        best_coef = linear2.coef_
        best_int = linear2.intercept_
        print("Co: \n", linear2.coef_)
        print("Intercept: \n", linear2.intercept_)
    else:
        print("\n\tFit Discarded.")
    loop_num += 1

print("\nBest Acccuracy: \n%4.3f" % best_acc)
print("\nBest Coefficients: \n", best_coef)
print("\nBest Intercept: \n", best_int)

# Plot Accuracy over time
x_scale = []
for x in range(max_iter + 1):
    x_scale.append(x)

plt.plot(x_scale, acc_counter, color='green', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3, marker='o',
         markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=5)

ymax = max(acc_counter)
ymin = min(acc_counter)
xpos = acc_counter.index(ymax)
xmax = x_scale[xpos]
annot_max_acc = str(ymax)
plt.annotate('Max Accuracy = ' + annot_max_acc[0:4], xy=(xmax, ymax), xycoords='data', xytext=(.8, .95),
             textcoords='axes fraction',
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05), horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')
plt.ylim(ymin, 1.0)
plt.xlabel('Run Number')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Prediction Accuracy over Time')
plt.show()

# Create model with best coefficients from above
new_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
new_model.intercept_ = best_int
new_model.coef_ = best_coef

# Predict y values for 1st model (not best) then compute difference between predictions and actual values
print("\n\n\nBREAK")
comp = []
predictions = linear.predict(x_test1)
for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[x], x_test1[x], y_test1[x])
    diff = sqrt((predictions[x] - y_test1[x])**2)
    print("\tDifference is ", diff)
    comp.append(diff)
print("\n\n\nBREAK")
print(comp)
print("\nSum of errors is ", sum(comp))

# Predict y values of best model (with optimal coefficients from above) using same x_test1 values as 1st model
# then compute difference between predictions and actual values
print("\n\n\nBREAK")
comp2 = []
predictions_new_model = new_model.predict(x_test1)
for x in range(len(predictions_new_model)):
    print(predictions_new_model[x], x_test1[x], y_test1[x])
    diff2 = sqrt((predictions_new_model[x] - y_test1[x])**2)
    print("\tDifference is ", diff2)
    comp2.append(diff2)

print("\n\n\nBREAK")
print(comp2)
print("\nSum of errors is ", sum(comp2))

print("\n\n\nFirst model fit difference: ", sum(comp))
print("\nSecond model fit difference ", sum(comp2))

print('\n1st model score: ',linear.score(x_train1, y_train1))

print('\nBest model score: ',new_model.score(x_train1, y_train1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code I’ve just realized that you’re using the same model (LinearRegression) and not changing any hyperparameters in any runs so there’s actually no improvement and the difference comes from the fact that you’ve split the data twice (and you didn’t give any random seed to it) so the slight difference comes from that. To improve the model you have to change the hyperparameters of the estimator. See more here: [hyperparameter tuning](https://www.google.com.tr/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-hyperparameter-tuning/amp/)

Comment: Brilliant answer and explanation, thank you so much for taking the time to help me on this!  I'm going to take a look at your other post  and I'll fix my code as you suggested.  The logical fallacy that you pointed out makes sense to me as well.  Thanks again!

Comment: One other question- I understand your point about using the same metric.  But I do print out and compare the first run with the "optimal" run R^2 scores, and they're typically extremely similar.  Shouldn't they be different if I did everything correctly, as that would be the same metric?

Comment: can you optimize and evaluate with the mean squared error instead and post the results?

Comment: I optimized on MSE as you asked, but kept the R^2 value just for reference.  This is what I get:  

   `1st model score:  0.8590411253845174  

    1st model MSE:  2.942428408301564  

    Best model score:  0.8591956695723348  

    Best model MSE:  2.9392023949709936`

Comment: Comparison part of code, at the end:

`new_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()  
new_model.intercept_ = best_int  
new_model.coef_ = best_coef  

predictions_new_model = new_model.predict(x_test1)  


print('\n1st model score: ', comp_acc)  
print('\n1st model MSE: ', comp_error)  
    # Print out R^2 accuracy and MSE using optimized model on same dataset as first run, for fair comparison  
new_model_error = mean_squared_error(y_test1, predictions_new_model)  
print('\nBest model score: ',new_model.score(x_test1, y_test1))  
print('\nBest model MSE: ', new_model_error)`

Comment: Looking at your code I’ve just realized that you’re using the same model (LinearRegression) and not changing any hyperparameters in any runs so there’s actually no improvement and the difference comes from the fact that you’ve split the data twice (and you didn’t give any random seed to it) so the slight difference comes from that. To improve the model you have to change the hyperparameters of the estimator. See more here: https://www.google.com.tr/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-hyperparameter-tuning/amp/

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  
I looked at the link you mentioned, but it didn't specify any hyperparameters for Linear Regression.  
I looked here, and the answer also specifies that there are no hyperparameters for linear regression.  Is this incorrect?  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31614/which-parameters-are-hyper-parameters-in-a-linear-regression

Comment: LR’s hyperparameters are given here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html it’s basic so it doesn’t have much. You only have your data and you are fitting a line where the line and your data points are the closest, so your choices are little, sklearn already fits it in the best way. It’s just statistics so not much optimization to do anyway, not like you have a search space or anything.